# Get current GPS coordinates on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an app that tracks the user's position. I do not know how to read gps location data from the BlackBerry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366609/how-to-read-the-current-location-in-a-blackberry-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it's all just a google search away:
[the essential bb api](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html?net/rim/device/api/gps/package-summary.html) (open on the net.rim.device.api.gps package) is always a good place to start and a lot of helpful info in the [blackberry support forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Location-APIs-Start-to-finish/ta-p/571949). And there is more where that came from.

I noticed that such broad questions are frowned upon in the stackoverflow community and you have a much bigger chance getting a helpful response if you present a more specific problem that can't easily be solved by using a search engine.