# How to read the current location in a blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, gps

How do I read the latitude and longitude of current location in a black berry application?

Answer (score 1):

Look at using these classes: [LocationProvider](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/location/LocationProvider.html#getLocation%28int%29), [Location](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/location/Location.html), [QualifiedCoordinates](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/location/QualifiedCoordinates.html).

```
LocationProvider provider = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);
Location loc = provider.getLocation(-1);
QualifiedCoordinates qc = loc.getQualifiedCoordinates();
//Call getLatitude() and getLongitude() in QualifiedCoordinates object.
```

Comment: is this the only code that i have to extend to the main class??

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.  That should be all the code you need to get the GPS coordinates of the device.  However, if you want to do something more e.g display those coordinates on the screen then of course you'll need more code.

Comment: what should i do next jonathan for getting the coordinates.Can u just give me a hint??

Comment: My answer to this question gives you all the code you need to get the coordinates.  If you need help doing something else like displaying the coordinates then you will have to ask for what you want.